# Model with target as feature for benchmark

Tags: regression, neural-networks, boosting

I was reading this article (https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-the-popularity-of-instagram-posts-deeb7dc27a8f) about predicting the popularity of Instagram post using different techniques and one of the steps the author takes is to use a XGBoost model with the target variable as a feature to get a benchmark score.

Anyone can explain me what is the point of this approach? Is it to have a guess about the maximum score a model without the target variable could get?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Does this mean that the model in the article is of a form similar to "y = f(y)"?

Answer (score 2):

This approach is not standard and not explained adequately in the post. In anything, if we used the target variable as a predictor as well as response in a adequately regularised linear model we should get: $R^2 = 1$. We do not get that (for reasons not explained in the post).

Response variables might be used as explanatory variables within the context of [list experiments](https://dimewiki.worldbank.org/wiki/List_Experiments) analysis, a particular questionnaire analysis methodology, but this is not the case here. (See for example, Imai et al. 2015 [*Using the Predicted Responses from List Experiments as Explanatory Variables in Regression Models*](https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/listExp.pdf))

In general, it *is* a good practice to have a basic model to serve as a benchmark. This approach is particular popular in forecasting (e.g. when using metrics like [MASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error) when the benchmark model is the one-step ahead forecast) and can be reasonably used in standard ML applications too. For example, when publishing a paper on a well-research area it is expected to benchmark a new model against known popular/good solutions. For personal use, it makes sense to use a simple model (e.g. a standard regularised regression approach using [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics))) to have an idea if we are actually doing better or just treading water. Notice that this is not a *maximum* score but rather a benchmark to surpass.

Comment: +1. A true benchmark would use permutation testing, for example target shuffling.